# Visual Studio Code no reconoce simbolos de R

Tags: r, vscode

VSC no me reconoce símbolos como el **`$, %>%`**, y demás.

Cuando pongo el símbolo luego del df sí me reconoce las variables pero luego el código me da error.

```
df$Enterprise ID
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "df$Enterprise ID"

Comment: vscode no es una ide.. es un editor con plugins, que hacen que funcione como ide (y justamente esta hecho de esa forma)... puede que sea un problema del plugin que estas usando...

Comment: Hay un espacio entre df$Enterprise y ID?

Comment: Sí, esta el espacio porque asi viene el nombre de la columna. Ahi probe con una sin espacios y me funcionó. Entonces deberia quitar todos los espacios de las columnas?

Comment: Para referenciar columnas con espacios tienes que usar el backtick: ` ``df$Enterprise ID`` `